# Restarting animation with callback values

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a looping animation which consist of few simple animations:

```
Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(this.state.animateUp, {toValue: 0, duration: 1500}),
        Animated.timing(this.state.fadeValue, {toValue: 1, duration: 500}),
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {toValue: 0, duration: 1000}),
          Animated.timing(this.state.frontRotation, { toValue: 1, duration: 300, }),
        ]),

        Animated.timing(this.state.toWhite, {toValue: 1, duration: 1000, delay: 11500}),
      ]);
```

I am trying to stop them on touch with a function which stops each animation like:

```
this.state.animateUp.stopAnimation(this.callback)
```

Then on second touch gesture i want to run the same animation with callback values. Is there any way of passing callback values back to the function and how it can be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Animation is not starting.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opacity: new Animated.Value(1),
      animateUp: new Animated.Value(-500),
      animateUpTime: new Animated.Value(1500),
      fadeValue: new Animated.Value(0),
      fadeValueTime: new Animated.Value(500),
      toWhite: new Animated.Value(0),
      toWhiteTime: new Animated.Value(11500),
      measurements: {},
      frontRotation: new Animated.Value(0),
      frontRotationTime: new Animated.Value(300),
      paused: false


    };
  }
  testPause(){
    this.animateUpListener = this.state.animateUp.addListener(({value}) => this.animateUpValue = value)
    this.fadeValueListener = this.state.fadeValue.addListener(({value}) => this.fadeValue = value)
    this.opacityListener = this.state.opacity.addListener(({value}) => this.opacityValue = value)
    this.frontRotationValueListener = this.state.frontRotation.addListener(({value}) => this.frontRotationValue = value)
    this.toWhiteListener = this.state.toWhite.addListener(({value}) => this.toWhiteValue = value)
    if(this.state.paused){
      this.state.animateUpTime = (1-this.animateUpValue)/1500
      this.state.fadeValueTime = (1-this.fadeValue)/500
      this.state.opacityValueTime = (1-this.opacityValue)/1000
      this.state.frontRotationTime = (1-this.frontRotationValue)/300
      this.state.toWhiteTime = (1-this.toWhiteValue)/11500


      this.setState({paused: false})
    } else {
      this.state.animateUp.stopAnimation();
      this.state.fadeValue.stopAnimation();
      this.state.opacity.stopAnimation();
      this.state.frontRotation.stopAnimation();
      this.state.toWhite.stopAnimation();
      this.setState({paused: true})}

}
  render() {
    var spin = this.state.frontRotation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '90deg']
    })


    return (

    );
  }

   animateFront() {

    return Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(this.state.animateUp, {toValue: 0, duration: this.state.animateUpTime}),
        Animated.timing(this.state.fadeValue, {toValue: 1, duration: this.state.fadeValueTime}),
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {toValue: 0, duration: this.state.opacityValueTime}),
          Animated.timing(this.state.frontRotation, { toValue: 1, duration: this.state.frontRotationTime, }),
        ]),

        Animated.timing(this.state.toWhite, {toValue: 1, duration: this.state.frontRotationTime, delay: 11500}),
      ]).start(() => this.restartAnimation());

   }

componentDidMount(){
  this.animateFront()
}
    restartAnimation(){
        this.animateUpValue = -500; //initialvalue
        this.fadeValue = 0; //initialvalue
        this.opacity = 1;
        this.toWhite = 0;
        this.frontRotation = 0;
        this.video.seek(0);
        this.state.animateUp.setValue(-500); //initialValue
        this.state.fadeValue.setValue(0); //initialValue
        this.state.opacity.setValue(1);
        this.state.toWhite.setValue(0);
        this.state.frontRotation.setValue(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by callback values? Could you elaborate on what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: When the component mounts, I am running animateFunction() which has those listed animations inside. I have created a button which stops all animations, and getting callback values(this.state.animateUp.stopAnimation(this.callback)). On second interaction with the button i would like to pass callback values received from stopAnimation  to animateFunction() and run it. (So in short, the button should work as a pause for animations). What i mean by callback values are the values in the moment of stoping animation.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement pause and resume by calculating the final value and time remaining at pause time and resume animation with those values.

First of all, add listeners to your animated values and save the values.

```
this.animateUpListener = this.state.animateUp.addListener(({value}) => this.animateUpValue = value);
this.fadeValueListener = this.state.fadeValue.addListener(({value}) => this.fadeValue = value);
```

Similarly, add listeners for all other animations. After that, sequence code will look like this.

```
Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(this.state.animateUp, {toValue: 0, duration: 1500}),
        Animated.timing(this.state.fadeValue, {toValue: 1, duration: 500}),
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {toValue: 0, duration: 1000}),
          Animated.timing(this.state.frontRotation, { toValue: 1, duration: 300, }),
        ]),

        Animated.timing(this.state.toWhite, {toValue: 1, duration: 1000, delay: 11500}),
      ]).start(() => this.restartAnimation());
```

When the button is pressed (first interaction), call stop animation on all animated values. At this point, values stored in listeners will have the value at which the animation was paused. For example, if animateUp had completed and fade was running, then this.fadeValue may have 0.25 etc value at this point. and this.state.animateUp will already have the final value i.e 0, so it won't run when we resume.

```
this.state.animateUp.stopAnimation();
this.state.fadeValue.stopAnimation();
```

Now you need to calculate the remaining time for the animation. if total time from fadeValue 0 to 1 is 1500 ((1-0)/1500) then, the time for the rest of the fade animation can be calculated in the same way ((1-0.25)/1500). This will be your duration of the animation for the resume part. The formula is ((finalValue - currentValue)/totalTime). Current value for each animation will be the value stored in listeners.

Now when the button is pressed again, you will calculate time remaining for the each animation values as described above and will start the animation sequence again with durations calculated above.If animateUp had completed and fadeValue was running, duration for animateUp using the formula will be 0. You will call the animation sequence with updated durations.

Once the sequence has completed, you can restart the sequence by resetting the current listener values of all the animations so that the durations are recalculated and all animation durations reset back to original values

```
restartAnimation() {
  this.animateUpValue = 0; //initialvalue
  this.fadeValue = 0; //initialvalue
  ...

  this.state.animateUp.setValue(0); //initialValue
  this.state.fadeValue.setValue(0); //initialValue
  ...
}
```

Let me know if you have any problems understanding.

Comment: Thank you, this really looks like a solution for my problem! However, should the listeners be added in the pauseFunction and after calculating current value how can i pass this value at the start of new sequence of animation?

Comment: You add listeners only once. They are added to the state variable that drives the animation (this.state.animateUp etc) so you don't need to add them again.

Comment: The animation takes place on values of state variables (this.state.animateUp etc) and when you pause the animation, the state variable will have the value it was paused at. At the time of resume, state variable will automatically start the animation back from the same value so you don't need to pass the start value again. The animation actually starts from the value of state variable. You only pass toValue and time. So we just need to update time of the animation when we resume. Also, please upvote the answer!

Comment: Thank you for further guidance. I my upvote for the answer is not visible for you unfortunately. Regarding listeners, I am still not sure where i should implement them in code: in this.state where i declare animated values? And regarding "resume" of animation, is it then enough to call the animation again?

Comment: I posted code i have so far, but i still cannot make it work.

Comment: Could you host your code somewhere on github and share the link with me. I could get it running and will let you know. Maybe just this one file with animations code.

Comment: Could you host your code somewhere on github and share the link with me. I could get it running and will let you know. Maybe just this one file with animations code.

Comment: @misi06 Could you host your code somewhere on github and share the link with me. I could get it running and will let you know. Maybe just this one file with animations code?